# Por qué obtengo el error IndexOutofBounds en este código?

Tags: java

Porque al añadir un objeto al arraylist me da el siguiente error :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 0?

```
    ArrayList<Producto> libreria = new ArrayList<>();
        libreria.add(Metodos.crearLibro("AA44", "La casa de Mickey Mouse", true, 10, "Anonimo", 200));
        libreria.add(Metodos.crearDVDMusica("AA74", "Firulais y sus amigos", true, 10, 10, "FiruGrande"));
        libreria.add(Metodos.crearPelicula("AA24", "FastAndFurius9", true, 10, 10, "ASEFASREF", "Autor2"));
        libreria.add(Metodos.crearLibro("AA04", "La casa de Mickey Mouse", true, 10, "Anonimo", 200));
        libreria.add(Metodos.crearLibro("AA34", "La argse", true, 10, "Anonimo", 200));

ArrayList<Producto> objet = new ArrayList<>();

//Bucle que recorre el arraylist libreria, y en la que si el objeto es de tipo libro lo añade en la arraylist objet 


for (int i = 1; i < libreria.size(); i++) {

            if (libreria.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Libro") == true) {

                objet.add(objet.get(i));

            }

        }
```

Comment: Si solo lo tradujeras seria **Índice 3 fuera de límites para longitud 0**, estas accediendo a una posición del array que no existe, debes asegurarte que al hacer un `.get(i)` haya un objeto en la posición dada en este caso la posición `3`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eh, es un error tipográfico. Estás añadiendo en `objet`, en la siguiente posición disponible, el elemento en la posición `i` de objet.

```
objet.add(objet.get(i));
```

Debería ser el objeto en la posición `i` de `librería`, según dices.

```
objet.add(libreria.get(i));
```

Answer (score -1):

1 -Si vas a guardar objetos de tipo `Libro` tu arrayList debe declararse como tipo Producto

```
ArrayList<Producto> objet = new ArrayList<>();
```

2- estas inicializando `i=1` debes tener presente que los indices de un array parten de 0.1.2...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < libreria.size(); i++)
```

3-Si estas buscando objetos de tipo Libro en el array Libreria xk agregas datos de array `object` en el mismo array `object` lo que debes agregar ahi son los objetos del array libreria en la posicion donde coincide la condicional `if`

```
for (int i = 0; i < libreria.size(); i++) {
        if (libreria.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Libro")) {
            objet.add(libreria.get(i));

        }

    }
```